# What is Ext.Component.initialConfig, what does it do, and in what context is it used?

Tags: extjs

When does initialConfig get called? What's the difference between it and initComponent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`initialConfig` never gets called, because it is not a function.
It's the configuration object, that was used to configure the component when it was actually created.

For example when you do:

```
var textField = new Ext.form.TextField({
  fieldLabel: 'A textfield',
  itemId: 'textField'
});
```

the

```
{
  fieldLabel: 'A textfield',
  itemId: 'textField'
}
```

object becomes a read only property `textField.initialConfig`

`initComponent()` is a private function, that is responsible for configuring the component during creation.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialConfig is what is used when the component fires it's constructor in initComponent().